# Calculating Lambert W Function

Tags: approximation, lambert-w

I'm trying to evaluate Lambert W Function , I used the formula 
$$ W(z)e^{W(z)} = z \Rightarrow W(z) = \frac{z}{W(z)} $$
$$ W(z) \approx ln(z)-ln(ln(z)-ln(...)) $$
But the result is very bad If I used ln(z)-ln(ln(z)) when it used in solving many cases like : 
$$ x^x = 100 \Rightarrow x = 3.015 $$ which is very far from 100 (27.68) . It works good in big values as shown in this [graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gMhS5.png).
I've searched and found this equation :
$$ L_1 - L_2 + \sum_{i=0}^\infty \sum_{j=0}^\infty (-1)^i \begin{bmatrix} i+j \\ i+1 \end{bmatrix}\frac{L_2\strut^{j}}{L_1\strut^{(i+j)}(i)!} \\ $$
$$ \text{Where} \hspace{10pt}L_1:ln(x), \hspace{10pt} L_2:ln(ln(x)) $$
Tried it but worse than the previous one and wolfram can't solve more than 15 terms but it can solve W(x) with prefect accuracy although i found the last formula on wolfram reference, so my question is " Is there a better way or formula to calculate Lambert W Function with high accuracy ? "
another small question : I've used Taylor Series Expansion for Lambert W Function 
$$ W(z) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty (-k)^{(k-1)}\frac{z^k}{k!} $$
but the radius of convergence is 1/e ,so it's not useful for real computations and wolfram formula works for x > e is there a way to get the values in between 1/e and e

Comment: Just use Newton-Raphson with the function $f(x)=xe^x-a$ to calculate $W(a)$.

Comment: Something must have gone wrong during the use of the formula involving Stirling numbers. It is known to be convergent for $x\geq e$ (cf. https://arxiv.org/pdf/1208.0754.pdf) and it works pretty well.

Comment: @Gary I don't know why it doesn't work well, yes it works but the given example $$ x^x = 100 $$ the error in x value doesn't exceed 0.3 but when using it in the equation it goes far away from the right answer

Comment: How do you want to solve $x^x=100$ with the $W$-function? It would be used to solve $x e^x =100$. Am I missing something?

Comment: @Gary \begin{gather}
     x^x = 100 \hspace{10pt} \text{take ln for both sides}
\\   xln(x) = ln(100) \Rightarrow ln(x)e^{ln(x)}=ln(100)
\\   \text{let u} = ln(x) \Rightarrow ue^u = ln(100)
\\   u = W(ln(100)) \Rightarrow x = e^u
 \end{gather}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\require{begingroup} \begingroup$
$\def\e{\mathrm{e}}\def\W{\operatorname{W}}\def\Wp{\operatorname{W_0}}\def\Wm{\operatorname{W_{-1}}}$

Is there any need to reinvent the wheel? 
Just use 
[Halley's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halley%27s_method),
which provides successive approximations to 
$w = \W(z)$ (so $z = w\exp(w)$) being

\begin{align} 
w_{j+1}
&=
w_j-{\frac {w_j \exp(w_j)-z}
{\exp(w_j)(w_j+1)-
\displaystyle\frac{(w_j+2)(w_j\exp(w_j)-z)}{2w_j+2}}}
\end{align}

as an established very efficient way 
[to calculate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function#Numerical_evaluation) 
$\W(x)$.

You can even check out open-source code, like for example, `specfunc/lambert.c`, 
which is part of [GSL - GNU Scientific Library](https://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/), for the details of realization.

$\endgroup$

Comment: Great that works very well, Regarding reinvent the wheel I was trying to evaluate W(x) using series, I could use Newton's Method which I know already and those methods supposed to be work well , But thanks anyway.